# Consider a wire with a current flowing through it: You could place a test charge near the wire and no force would be applied to the charge. Why?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, magnetic-fields

Consider a wire with a current flowing through it:

"You could place a test charge near the wire and no force would be applied to the charge.
This is because there are exactly the same number of moving electrons and protons in each section of the wire."

Reference: Griffiths: Introduction to Electrodynamics, first page of the chapter on magnetostatics.

I paraphrase because I translated the statement from German into English.

Comment: I mean, he answers the question in the second sentence of your quote: equal numbers of electrons and protons means the net charge is zero, so it creates no electric field to apply a force on the test charge. This is of course and *approximation*: there are small variations in the electric field near the wire because of the discrete nature of the charge-carrying particles, but it's nowhere near strong enough to appreciably push on charges.

Comment: yes, I should have elaborated my question. I would have thought that the motion of the electrons is not so homogeneous, because the impact with particles of the wire is statistically distributed i.e. in some sections of the wire more electrons flow  than in others. Even if it is a wire with a 100% homogeneous material, so that in each section the same amount of protons is present. There would be a negative net charge in such a section

Comment: Think of the wire without a voltage drop, so no current flows. The number of electrons and protons is equal and opposite and there is no charge. Put a voltage drop and get a steady current through the length x of the wire. As many electrons enter the x wire  length ,equal in number to the ones that leave the wire to go to the rest of the circuit, So the charge of a delta(x) of the length x of the wire, remains neutral, keeping in mind the observation made by @march on small variations

Comment: In truth, the charge will [induce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrostatic_induction) some opposite charge nearby, resulting in an attractive force. This force is typically small enough to be neglected, and has nothing to do with the current flow.

Comment: @Puk The definition of test charge is understood in the limit as the test charge goes to zero, so if one is talking about an actual theoretical test charge then no induced charge or force. In a real experiment, though, yeah.

Comment: @AlbertusMagnus If the wire were charged, there would be a force proportional to the external charge $q$, which I would point out also goes to zero as $q\rightarrow0$. You are right in the sense that the induction force, proportional to $q^2$, would be negligible in comparison for small $q$. However since the induction force is the only one to speak of here, it is difficult to even define what a test charge means or in what sense it is small/negligible.

Comment: @Puk. Equally so, it is difficult to define what an induction force means when it is a test charge what produces it. This is the reason we use the concept of test charge in the first place; it allows us to understand field lines that arise from Laplace's eq. because the test charge is for all practical purposes decoupled from the larger system. Of course I think a real life test charge (not a mathematical one) would produce exactly the effect which you speak of. At this point we are probably quibbling over nothing.

Comment: @AlbertusMagnus We do agree on the actual physics, but how do you define a test charge? Is there an established definition that allows us to say the induction force on it is zero? We can speak of a "small" charge, but there isn't really anything here that allows us but a bound on how small it must be to be considered a test charge, or sweep the induction force under the rug because it is the only force.

Comment: @Puk. We agree. I think the rule is only that either number (charge/force) can be made as small as one likes and that the expressions we write from Maxwell's laws are only as accurate as the degree to which both tend to zero.